# get time of Different Timezone

Tags: timezone, timestamp

**My task:** I am going to run a contest world wide at my website. A problem setter will set problems from a specific area of the world setting a time and date of starting time of the contest. I have to show that time correctly all over the world so the the contest starts at a time everywhere of the world.
**My Idea :** I planed to get the time from the problem setter of his time zone using server site language like php time(), & will store to database converting to timezone= zero (0). And who are going to attend the contest I'll just add hour(s) of that time zone with my database time.
**Need help:** I have no Idea how to convert that timestamps to timezone 'zero', even how can I get the ±hour(s) of current timezone?
*Thank you...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1:
Let the user choose his timezone. You could fill a dropdown with values from this site: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Step 2:
Convert the timezone to servertime

```
$timezone_client = new DateTimeZone('America/Denver');
$timezone_server = new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru');
$datetime = new DateTime('2013-01-25 12:00:00', timezone_client);
$datetime->setTimezone($timezone_server);
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Thank you.
Can't I detect client's timezone using code? I think client will fill pain if he needs to select his timezone to attend the contest.

Comment: Its not trivial, but you may find this article interesting: http://www.onlineaspect.com/2007/06/08/auto-detect-a-time-zone-with-javascript/

Comment: Wow!!! it returns timezone offset in Minutes but in inverse sign. I may solve my problem now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Timezone 0 = "UTC" (sometimes called GMT)
Your system / language will have a Timezone class, which provides difference to GMT/UTC

Comment: I don't know that class, I'm using php, may you help?